# How to sync Argo workflow-templates b/w a git-repo and Argo instance?

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, argo-workflows, argo

I have a git repository(hosted on Github) where I create my workflow-template YAMLs, and upload them to Argo via UI or REST-api. Now whenever I update any workflow-template, I have to manually update it in 2 places, the git-repo and Argo. There is a chance of either place being missed in this process.
How can I automate the process of updating workflow-templates in Argo-service, whenever the workflow-templates in git repository change?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in many ways.

1. you have ArgoCD to do CD on GitOps. It will make sure synced with desired state from GitHub(preferred)
2. you can use Argo workflow event binding to trigger workflow on GitHub action and get the change from GitHub and apply it. https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/342abcd6d72b4cda64b01f30fa406b2f7b86ac6d/docs/events.md